# Lebesgue Measurable/Integrable Functions and Singular Linear Transformations

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, linear-transformations

The following theorem is paraphrased from Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and their Applications*.

> Suppose $T \in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$. If $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, so is $f \circ T$. If $f \geq 0$ or $f$ is integrable with respect to the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue meseaure, then
>   $$ \int f(x) \mathrm{d}x = |\det T| \int f \circ T(x) \mathrm{d}x.$$
>   If $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, then $T(E)$ is also Lebesgue measurable, and $m(T(E)) = |\det T|m(E)$.

One of the exercises asks how much of this remains true if $T$ is not invertible.

Now, assuming that $f \circ T$ is Lebesgue measurable, we do not necessarily have $\int f = |\det T| \int f \circ T$ because $\int f$ might be nonzero, whereas $|\det T| = 0$. **However, how do we show that $f \circ T$ is or is not Lebesgue measurable?**

I started by assuming that $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a Borel set. Then $(f \circ T)^{-1}(E) = T^{-1}(f^{-1}(E))$. Since $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, we know that $f^{-1}(E)$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, so $f^{-1}(E) = F \cup N$, where $F$ is a Borel set and $N$ is a Lebesgue-null set. Then
$$T^{-1}(f^{-1}(E)) = T^{-1}(F \cup N) = T^{-1}(F) \cup T^{-1}(N).$$
Of course, since $F$ is Borel and $T$ is continuous, we know that $T^{-1}(F)$ is Borel. But what do we do with $T^{-1}(N)$?

**I am also unsure on how to show that $T(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable whenever $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, but I believe this is true.**

As for the claim that $m(T(E)) = |\det T| m(E)$, since $\det T = 0$, we would have to show that $m(T(E)) = 0$. Since $T$ is singular, $T(E)$ is a subset of some subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that is not the whole space, so $T(E)$ is a subset of a null set. Since Lebesgue measure is complete, $m(T(E)) = 0$. (I still have to formalize this idea, but I think I'm on the right track here.)

Answer (score 1):

I owe the idea of this answer to the earlier answer by Andreas Blass. I will post this answer because it took me some effort to formalize the argument made by him.

> **Lemma**. Let $(X,\mathcal M, \mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal N,\nu )$ be complete $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, and let $(X\times Y, \mathcal L, \lambda )$ be the completion of $(X\times Y, \mathcal M\otimes \mathcal N, \mu \times \nu).$ If $E\in \mathcal L$ is a $\lambda $-null set, then $E^y\in \mathcal M$ for a.e. $y\in Y$. (In fact, $\mu (E^y)=0$ for a.e. $y$.)

Here $E^y=\{x\in X\mid(x,y)\in E\}$.

(Proof.) Find a $N\in\mathcal M\otimes \mathcal N$ such that $\lambda(N)=0$ and $E\subset N$. Then Tonelli's theorem implies that $$0=\lambda(N)=\int\mu(N^y)d\nu,$$so $\mu(N^y)=0$ for a.e. $y\in Y$. Since $E^y\subset N^y$, completeness of $\mu$ implies that whenever $\mu(N^y)=0$,  we have $E^y\in \mathcal M$ and $\mu(E^y)=0$. The claim follows. $\square$

> **Corollary**. If $A\subset \mathbb R$ is non-Lebesgue measurable, then $A\times \mathbb R$ is not Lebesgue measurable.

(Proof.) If $A\times \mathbb R$ were Lebesgue measurable, then by the above lemma $(A\times \mathbb R)^y$ would be Lebesgue measurable for some $y\in \mathbb R$. But since $(A\times \mathbb R)^y=A$, this is impossible. $\square$

Now let $A\subset \mathbb R$ be any non-Lebesgue measurable set, let $f:\mathbb R ^2\to \mathbb R$ be the characteristic function of $A\times \{0\}$, and let $T:\mathbb R ^2\to \mathbb R^2$ be the projection onto the first coordinate. Then $f$ is Lebesgue measurable and $T$ is a linear transformation, but $f\circ T$ is not Lebesgue measurable. Indeed, $(f\circ T)^{-1}(1)=A\times \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

"What do we do with $T^{-1}(N)$?" We use it to build a counterexample. Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be a nice well-behaved function, say identically zero, except that on some proper linear subspace, say the $x$-axis, it's completely wild. So $f$ is Lebesgue measurable because its wildness is on a set of measure zero. But if $T$ is the projection of $\mathbb R^2$ onto the $x$-axis, then in $f\circ T$ the wildness permeates all of $\mathbb R^2$ and you can thus arrange for $f\circ T$ not to be Lebesgue measurable.